# PHP force download of file - either getting download interruped or system says invalid/corrupt file

Tags: php, download

What I am trying to implement is force download of a file through PHP.
There are 2 issues that I am facing, and I've broken my head thinking about what is possibly going wrong here.

1. Whenever I try to download the file using IE, the download gets interrupted about midway i.e. say my file is 1024Kb in size, around 500Kb is when the download stops as I get an error message in IE say 'Download was interrupted'
2. The other issue that I encounter frequently (but not always) is that the downloaded file (which is actually a zip file) gets corrupted at times for some reason! The file on the server is alright - if I download it directly from there, no issues at all. However, if I download using my PHP script and then try to unzip the file - Windows says 'Invalid or corrupt file...'

I really need some help on this.

Following is the block of code downloading the file:-

```
$fileName = "./SomeDir/Somefile.zip";
$fsize = filesize($fileName); 
set_time_limit(0);

// required for IE, otherwise Content-Disposition may be ignored
if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');


// set headers
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($fileName)."\";");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header("Content-Length: " . $fsize);

// download
$file = @fopen($fileName,"rb");
if ($file) {
  while(!feof($file)) {
print(fread($file, 1024*8));
flush();
if (connection_status()!=0) {
  @fclose($file);
  die();
}
}
@fclose($file);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php

$file = "./SomeDir/Somefile.zip";
set_time_limit(0);
$name = "Somefile.zip";

// Print headers and print to output.
header('Cache-Control:');
header('Pragma:');
header("Content-type: application/zip");
header("Content-Length: ". filesize($file));
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$name}\"");
readfile($file);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. Tried this, and it seems to show the same behavior :( At times the downloaded file is corrupted or invalid and IE abruptly stops the download and says 'download was interrupted'

Comment: Possibly try using a different Content Type: Instead of application/zip, try using application/octet-stream. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your content-length reports more bytes than the amount really transferred.
Check in the server's log. The server could gzip the content and when it closes the connection the client is still waiting for the remaining declared bytes.

Comment: This post could be a comment